# Не удается запустить приложение в графическом режиме по ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, x11

Подключаюсь по ssh. Когда пытаюсь запустить приложение в графическом режиме, выдает вот такое:

```
user user # ssh root@192.168.1.241 -X
root@192.168.1.241's password: 
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Linux roboard1 3.2.0-4-486 #1 Debian 3.2.46-1 i586

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Jun 15 06:28:16 2016 from 192.168.1.244
root@roboard1:~# aghves
Executing: /usr/lib/squeak/4.10.2-2614/squeakvm -encoding UTF-8 -vm-display-x11 -plugins /usr/share/aghves/Plugins/:/usr/lib/squeak/4.10.2-2614/ /usr/share/aghves/Aghves.image 
Could not open display `(null)'.
root@roboard1:~#
```

Вот файл конфигурации в удленном компютере `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Подключение производится с Linux Mint 17.3 (kernel 3.19.0-32-generic) на   Debian (kernel 3.2.0-4-486)

На удалённом компьютере:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep 'libx11\|xauth'
libx11-6:i386               install
libx11-data                 install
libx11-dev:i386             install
libx11-doc                  install
libx11-xcb1:i386            install
xauth                       install
```

Вывод команды:

```
$ ssh -vvv user@192.168.1.241 -X
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.241 [192.168.1.241] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.241" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 49:fb:e5:ca:27:ca:f2:10:e4:df:1e:9b:80:2c:ee:ca
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.241" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.1.241' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@192.168.1.241's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 53 padlen 11 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.241 ([192.168.1.241]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_VTNR
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = hy_AM
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = hy_AM
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = hy_AM
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = hy_AM
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = hy_AM
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env CLUTTER_BACKEND
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env GDM_XSERVER_LOCATION
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = hy_AM
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_PID
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = hy_AM
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env MDM_XSERVER_LOCATION
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SEAT
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env MDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAIN
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env MDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env TEXTDOMAINDIR
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = hy_AM
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux roboard1 3.2.0-4-486 #1 Debian 3.2.46-1 i586

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have new mail.
Last login: Wed Jun 15 09:21:25 2016 from 192.168.1.244
user@roboard1:~$
```

Содержимое `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` из локальной машины:

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
   ForwardX11 yes
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Это локальный. Удачно запускается:

```
user@user ~ $ xeyes 
user@user ~ $ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

Это удаленный. Не запускается:

```
user@roboard1:~$ xeyes 
Error: Can't open display: roboard1:10.0
user@roboard1:~$ echo $DISPLAY
roboard1:10.0
user@roboard1:~$
```

Вывод команды sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP:6012 -sTCP:LISTEN

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    14287 user    9u  IPv4  26801      0t0  TCP *:6012 (LISTEN)
```

telnet localhost 6012

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Trying ::1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: После внесения изменения в конфиг, sshd перезапускали? `$ sudo /etc/init.d/sshd reload`

Comment: Да, и reload, и restart. Не помог.

Comment: приведите прямо в тексте вопроса вывод команды `$ dpkg --get-selections | grep 'libx11\|xauth'`, выполненной на удалённом компьютере. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: вывод команды добавил в вопрос

Comment: А что нам говорит `set |grep DISPLAY`?

Comment: Пробовали назначать вручную переменную типа `export DISPLAY=:0`?

Comment: set | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=roboard1:10.0

Comment: 1. а что-нибудь попроще запускается? *xeyes*, например. 2. попробуйте подключаться под другим пользователем (можете, заодно, заглянуть в `/root/.ssh/config`). 3. если всё неудачно, подключитесь не-root-ом с опциями `-vvv`: `$ ssh -vvv ...` и приведите в вопросе весь вывод. 4. приведите `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` и `~/.ssh/config` с локальной машины.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ничего не запускается. Под другими пользователями та-же проблема.  /root/.ssh/config и ~/.ssh/config файла нет. Выводы команд добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @approximatenumber - нет, подскажите как?

Comment: @Timeon, судя по информации в приведённом логе, вы подключаетесь из-под локального пользователя root. с огромной вероятностью локальная x-сессия у вас запущена от имени другого пользователя (если вообще запущена), соответственно, доступа к x-сессии у вас нет. запускайте команду `ssh -X ...` из окна эмулятора терминала от имени того же пользователя, под которым запущена x-сессия (и внутри которой запущен данный эмулятор терминала).

Answer (score 4):

> Вывод команды ssh -vvv user@192.168.1.241 -X
>   `debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1`

судя по информации в приведённом логе, вы подключаетесь из-под локального пользователя `root`.

с огромной долей вероятности локальная *x-сессия* у вас запущена от имени другого пользователя (если вообще запущена), соответственно, доступа к *x-сессии* у программы *ssh* — нет.

запускайте команду `ssh -X ...` из окна эмулятора терминала от имени **того же** пользователя, под которым запущена *x-сессия* (и внутри которой запущен данный эмулятор терминала).

---

**дополнение**:

возможно, стоит ещё добавить опцию `-Y` при вызове программы *ssh* для разрешения «доверенного» *x11-forwarding*.

---

**диагностика**:

после подключения с пробросом x-сессии программа *sshd* на удалённой стороне начинает слушать tcp-порт, номер которого (как и принято у *x-сервера*) равен 6000 плюс номер дисплея.

номер дисплея (на удалённой стороне) можно посмотреть в переменной окружения `$DISPLAY`:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:12.0
```

здесь 12 — это номер дисплея. соответственно, порт будет 6012, и проверить, слушает ли его *sshd* можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP:6012 -sTCP:LISTEN
sshd    30541   al    9u  IPv6 457232      0t0  TCP [::1]:6012 (LISTEN)
sshd    30541   al   10u  IPv4 457233      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6012 (LISTEN)
```

видно, что *sshd* слушает обращения на loopback-адресах: `127.0.0.1` (ipv4) и `[::1]` (ipv6).

в принципе, этот трафик может быть заблокирован средствами *netfilter-а*. что-нибудь вроде:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6012 -j DROP
```

поэтому имеет смысл проверить эти правила программой `iptables-save` на наличие подобной блокировки.

возможно, кстати, имеет смысл проверить и несколько других портов, начиная с 6010 (*sshd* начинает присвоение номеров с 10-го дисплея): они могут быть заняты каким-нибудь локальным процессом (тем же подвисшим *sshd*, например).

Comment: Запустил так, как вы сказали, но проблема осталась. Пишет " Error: Can't open display:  ".

Comment: @Timeon, по шагам: завершите ssh-сессию. в текущем сеансе оболочки запустите *xeyes*. если запускается, приведите результат `$ echo $DISPLAY`, затем повторите `$ ssh -X ...` и приведите результат той же команды (`$ echo $DISPLAY`), выполненной уже на удалённой машине.

Comment: Результат добавил к вопросу

Comment: Добовление опции -Y не решил проблему. А также попробовал команду sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP:порт -sTCP:LISTEN , пишет lsof: command not found

Comment: вывод команды добавил в вопрос. Похоже у меня проблема с IPv6.

Comment: @Timeon, наоборот, абсолютно никаких проблем с ipv6. а почему вы проверяли порт 6012, если у вас номер дисплея — 10? открыли уже несколько ssh-сессий с пробросом x-трафика?

Comment: Нет, сессия одна. Команда echo &DISPLAY выводил 12, хотя вчера было 10. Стоит добавить результат программы iptables-save?

Comment: @Timeon, если вы не знаете, как проанализировать, не блокируется ли соответствующий трафик, то добавляйте. а лучше, конечно, просто проверить telnet-ом (понятно, на удалённой стороне): `$ telnet localhost 6012`. что должен выводить telnet в случае удачного или неудачного подключения, вы, надеюсь, в курсе?

Comment: Добавил вывод программы telnet

Comment: @Timeon, unreachable — это уже явно про ipv6. но первая попытка была именно по ipv4. судя по всему, неудачная. чтобы telnet «сосредоточился» только на ipv4, можете либо явно указать ipv4-адрес localhost-а: 127.0.0.1, либо передать опцию `-4`.

Comment: кстати, то, что ipv6 — unreachable, уже свидетельствует о проблемах с ipv6. если он там не нужен, можно отключить: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6